# Is it really necessary to clear the timers before unmounting the component?

Tags: reactjs

Usually timers will be cleared before unmounting the component from DOM. But what would be the side effects if we forgot to clear the timers?

Comment: Yes. Timer should be cleared on component unmount.

Comment: @Ved Why even write this comment? If you want to answer the question, then write an answer. Then, if you're going to write an answer, write the reason why as well.

Comment: @ElliotSchep comment also helps. And as soon as I wrote the comment, one correct answer also added.

Comment: It *does* help, that’s why I don’t understand why you didn’t just write an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you call a `timer` in some function and when you navigate to another component and your current component has `unmounted`, if you do not clear the timer, your function will continue to be executed.

Hence in the `componentWillUnmount` function you need to clear the timer which can be identified by the numeric value returned by `setInterval`

AS mentioned in the React DOCS:

> `componentWillUnmount()` is invoked immediately before a component is
>   unmounted and destroyed. Perform any necessary cleanup in this method,
>   such as invalidating timers, canceling network requests, or cleaning
>   up any DOM elements that were created in componentDidMount

Example:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.somefunc(),
      1000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }
```

**SideEffect:**

Consider a case when in the timer you are making the API call from which you are getting data that you display in your component. Now if you navigate away from the component you wouldn't normally want to be calling the API again and again even though you don't need the result. This will cause and Unnecessary load on the Server.

Comment: one doubt, component will get unmounted means all its properties methods will not exist, so ideally it should throw error that `somefunc` is not present, how the reference of all the methods and other values that we imported will exist after that?

Comment: The purpose of clearing timer inside  `componentWillUnmount()`  is to cancel the pending timer. But I think it will not keep executing.

Comment: Not sure how it is executed if it does, but I have a call in my local where even though the component has unmounted API calls are getting executed since I did not clear my timer

Comment: @Ved @MayankShukla Check this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk9o7.png. This is my code: `constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      
   };
   componentDidMount() {
     console.log('cdm called');
     setInterval( () => this.tick(), 1000)

   }
   componentWillUnmount() {
     console.log('unmount called');
   }
   tick = () => {
       console.log('tick called');

   }`

Comment: @MayankShukla, you can check this behaviour yourself, here is a test repository that I have, https://github.com/mayankshubham/ReactReduxApp.
build the code using `npm run build` and run using `npm start` after installing node_modules

Comment: Just saving the timerId with `this.timerId` did not work for me with react 16. In `componentWillUnmount()` the timerId could not be found and the clearing were not save.
 I solved it by saving the id directly in the component state. So you will just call `this.state.timerID`.